# Magento 2.1: adminhtml errors on the edit product page

Tags: magento-2.1, error, adminhtml

We are running into some strange errors with our Magento 2.1.9 installation. When opening a edit product page in the backend, the page shows some different inline errors:

```
Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/nl_NL/Magento_Ui/templates/form/components/single/switcher.html' #0

 [path-to-magento-public]/vendor/magento/framework/App/StaticResource.php(97): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile() #1
 [path-to-magento-public]/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource->launch() #2
 [path-to-magento-public]/pub/static.php(13): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource)) #3 {main}
```

There are numurous errors on the page, all related to the `adminhtml/Magento/backend/nl_NL/Magento_Ui/templates/form/components/single` reference.

I've been trough the loop a few times here with the following commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

And even more. I've cleared caches, removed di/generation folders, switched deployment modes back and forth, but still no luck.

I'm running out of ideas here, so I was hoping someone ran into the same problem and managed to find the culprit. I've added a screenshot to give you guys/gals some reference.

[image]